# Show that a directed multi graph having no isolated vertices has an Euler Circuit iff ...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Show that a directed multi-graph having no isolated vertices has an Euler circuit *iff* the graph is weakly connected and $\text{deg}^{\text{in}} = \text{deg}^{\text{out}}$ for each vertex.

The problem I am having is understanding how to reduce the statement into two parts because of the "if and only if".

I came up with the following things I have to prove:

1. If the graph has an Euler circuit then it is weakly connected
2. If the graph has an Euler circuit then each vertex must have $\text{deg}^{\text{in}} = \text{deg}^{\text{out}}$

Is this correct? How does one reduce statements of the form $C$ iff $A$ *and* $B$?

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT**

Is splitting the problem like so, correct?

1. If the multigraph (with no isolated vertices) has an Euler Circuit then the graph is weakly connected and $\text{deg}^{\text{in}} = \text{deg}^{\text{out}}$
2. If the graph is weakly connected and $\text{deg}^{\text{in}} = \text{deg}^{\text{out}}$ then the multigraph (with no isolated vertices) has an Euler Circuit?